# Can't sign in to Atlassian Bitbucket from brave browser

Tags: bitbucket, brave

When I try to login to my Bitbucket in brave browser, Atlassian displays the error below:

> You may run into this issue when you use specific browsers or add-ons that hide the referrer header for id.atlassian.com and other Atlassian sites. Check for these and then try logging in again.'

Is there any way to fix this?

Answer (score 0):

A workaround is to disable the shield while you perform the login action.

For a permanent fix, id.atlassian.com needs to be added to the Whitelist of Referrer Headers in Brave.

It seems it's already there in GitHub: https://github.com/brave/referrer-whitelist/blob/master/data/ReferrerWhitelist.json

However, you may have to use a beta version or clone the repository with the latest whitelist for it to work for you.

In my case I found the file under:

`/home/<username>/snap/brave/84/.config/BraveSoftware/Brave-Browser/<afa...al>/1.0.35/1/ReferrerWhitelist.json`

But a simple `find ~ -name ReferrerWhitelist.json` will throw the exact location for you.

Not sure where the file will be stored on a Windows or Mac client, though.
On a Mac, it should be almost identical to Linux. On Windows, the file is likely to show up under `%LOCALAPPDATA%\BraveSoftware\` or `%APPDATA%\BraveSoftware\`.

Comment: Turning off brave shields worked for me. But I want to know where do I paste the json file of the whitelist?

Comment: I edited my answer with the details as to where to find the file on a Linux box. Finding it on a Mac should be almost identical. On a Windows box, search your machine for the file.